# Mock a dependency of a WP_REST_Controller class

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, testing

I have a custom WordPress REST API with a client for an external service being injected in its constructor; that client is going to be used internally in that class, like this:

```php
class Custom_REST_Endpoint extends WP_REST_Controller {
  public function __construct( $client ) {
    $this->client = $client;
  }
}
```

Then, I'm registering that REST API, like this:

```php
function custom_api_register_routes() {
    $api = new Custom_REST_Endpoint( new Client() );
    $api->register_routes();
 }

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_api_register_routes' );
```

- That said, what's the best/correct/WordPress-ish approach for mocking that `Client` object while doing a test?
- Is there some hook available I can hook in and swap `Clients` implementation by the mocked one?
- Do you recommend a different approach for injecting `Client` into `Custom_REST_Endpoint`?